# Probability of guests in theater getting their reserved seats

Tags: probability

> *Exercise:* Consider a theater with $n$ seats that is fully booked for this evening.
>   Each of the $n$ people entering the theater (one by one) has a seat reservation. However, the first person is absent-minded and takes a seat at random. Any subsequent
>   person takes his or her reserved seat if it is free and otherwise picks a free seat at
>   random.
>
> (i) What is the probability that the last person gets his or her reserved seat?
>
> (ii) What is the probability that the $k$th person gets his or her reserved seat?

I get $p = 0.5$ for (i), but I have no idea if it's right.

Can somebody help me with (i) and especially (ii)?

Thank you!

Comment: I would say advanced (graduate level?) probability.

Comment: I suggest you search MSE for "taking seats on a plane."

Comment: Check Byron Schmuland's answer for $ii)$

Comment: @Committing to a challenge : Thanks, that's it!